# Custom File Upload button to show file name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having trouble changing the label of my customized File Upload button to show the file name after file has been selected.

Tried to follow [these steps](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/).

The button shows correctly and the file is uploaded, but I can't manage to make the JS work to show the uploaded files name on the button.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.wpcf7-file');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var label = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-file-button');
    var fileName = '';
    fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
    if (fileName) {
      label.innerHTML = fileName;
    } else
      label.innerHTML = labelVal;

  });
});
```

```css
label.custom-file-button {
  position: relative;
}

label.custom-file-button:before {
  content: " Take or upload picture";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #1b87d5;
  color: #fff;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.custom-file-button:hover:before {
  background: #146bac;
}

.custom-file-input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="limit-to-view">
  <label class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap custom-file-button">
      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap custom-file-input">
        <input type="file" name="custom-file-input" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.odt,.avi,.ogg,.m4a,.mov,.mp3,.mp4,.mpg,.wav,.wmv" aria-invalid="false">
      </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. Substituted `.closest()` for `.querySelectorAll()` to select closest ancestor `<label>` element to the current `<input type="file">` element. Since the `<input type="file">` element is the child of the `<label>` setting `.innerHTML` to the file name would overwrite the `<input type="file">` element. The CSS does not display a `<span>` element that is first child of the `<label>`, added the `<span>` to display file name as `.nextElementSibling` of `<label>` element. You can use `e.target.files[0].name` to get the file name.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.wpcf7-file');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var label = e.target.closest('.custom-file-button');
    label.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = e.target.files[0].name;
  });
});
```

```css
label.custom-file-button {
  position: relative;
}

label.custom-file-button:before {
  content: " Take or upload picture";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #1b87d5;
  color: #fff;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.custom-file-button:hover:before {
  background: #146bac;
}

.custom-file-input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="limit-to-view">
  <label class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap custom-file-button">
      <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap custom-file-input">
        <input type="file" name="custom-file-input" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.odt,.avi,.ogg,.m4a,.mov,.mp3,.mp4,.mpg,.wav,.wmv" aria-invalid="false">
      </span>
    </label>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps!! That solved it for me. And thanks for the explanation :)